# How to change a variable of type object to type boolean in Python?

Tags: python, boolean

I am not a very experienced Python user, so this might be a very easy question for some people. I have a couple of variables that are set as `t` or `f` indicating `True` or `False`. When I look up their datatype using `df.info()`, I see that these variables are objects. However, I want them to become `booleans`. I looked on the internet but I cannot find a way to do this easily. Is there anyone who can help me out with this problem?

Comment: `variable == 't'`?

Comment: Are you working with Pandas? "t" and "f" would ordinarily be strings. In Pandas, you could probably do something like `df.my_col = df.my_col.str.match('^t$')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with column with `str` values of `'t'` and `'f'`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['t','f','t','f'], columns=['str'])
>>> df
  str
0   t
1   f
2   t
3   f
```

You can make a new column that does a string comparison that returns a `bool` representation

```
>>> df['bool'] = df['str'] == 't'
>>> df
  str   bool
0   t   True
1   f  False
2   t   True
3   f  False
```

Comment: I would caution against using things like `str` as column names when advising a (self-proclaimed) beginner.